# TYPO3: Multiple references for fieldName?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, extbase

Inside a custom content element, I use two fields: image and media

My setup.txt looks like this:

```
custom_ce {
        templateName = CustomCe
        dataProcessing {
            10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
            10 {
                references.fieldName = media
            }
            20 = Vendor\Ext\DataProcessing\CustomCeProcessor
        }
    }
```

Currently I managed to process only one field. Is it possible to pass **both** media and image fields to the filesProcessor ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call a DataProcessor more than once and you can specify the varibale the files are available in your fluid template with the `as` key:

```
custom_ce {
    templateName = CustomCe
    dataProcessing {
        10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
        10 {
            references.fieldName = media
            as = media
        }
        15 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
        15 {
            references.fieldName = image
            as = image
        }
        20 = Vendor\Ext\DataProcessing\CustomCeProcessor
    }
}
```